tkinter/tcl Update considered harmful. Is this msg still valid?
Are the concerns about using the w.update() method in tkinter/tcl expressed in this article still valid after more than two decades? Surely improvements have been made to mitigate the concerns with using this tkinter method in this modern era. If so, when should/can this method be used?
For example, in 2021 on SO the answer written by @Thingamabobs to the question When should I use root.update() in tkInter for python is never. @BryanOakley commented that it is a good answer and also cited the above mentioned tcl article.
From an opposite perspective, I came across Alan D. Moore's book on Python GUI Programming In Tkinter (2018), Chapter 10 on "Creating Automated Tests with unittest", mentioned the basis for using the w.update method on page 263. Quoting that section:

Managing asynchronous code
Whenever you interact with a Tkinter UI--whether it's clicking a
button, typing in a field, or raising a window, for example--the
response is not executed immediately in-place. Instead, these actions
actions are placed in a to-do list, called an event queue, to be
handled later while your code execution continues. While these actions
seem instant to users, test code cannot count on a requested action
being completed before the next line of code.
To solve this problem, we can use these special widget methods that
allow us to manage the event queue:
wait_visibility(): This method causes the program to wait until a
widget is fully drawn on-screen before executing the next line of
code.
update_idletasks(): This method forces Tkinter to process any idle
tasks currently outstanding on the widget. Idle tasks are low-priority
tasks such as drawing and rendering.
update(): This method forces Tkinter to process all events which are
outstanding on a widget, including calling callbacks, redraws and
geometry management. It includes everything that update_idletasks()
does and more.
The event queue will be discussed in more detail in Chapter 13,
Asynchronnous programming with Thread and Queue.

On page 276, he demonstrated how to use the .update() method in unit testing widgets.
He also wrote on page 363:

The update() and update_idletasks() methods
In Chapter 10, Creating Automated tests with unittest, you also
learned about the update() and update_idletasks() methods. To
review, these methods will cause Tkinter to execute any tasks
currently in the event queue; update() runs tasks currently waiting
in the queue until it's entirely clear, while update_idletasks()
only runs the idle tasks. This is generally less important and safer
code, so it's recommended to use update_idletasks() unless it doesn't
do the job.

I am writing a GUI that uses the Python thread and queue modules to load images to widgets asynchronously. Their correct implementation is ensured; everything works as expected. However, after placing a new widget that uses the w.lift() and w.lower() methods to hide and unhide the widgets affected by the thread-queue approach, the display of this placed widget becomes erroneous. When lifted, the background colour of this placed widget always assumes the colour of the widget in which it was placed in (defined by the in_ option). I have tried using the .update_idletask() method in every imaginable way to resolve this illogical appearance issue but failed. Finally, I tried replacing the .update_idletask() with the .update() method out of curiosity and that resolved the widget's appearance issue. I have always abided by the practice of not using the .update() method for tkinter programming when the .mainloop() method is called. This is my first encounter with needing to use the .update() method when the .mainloop() is called. Hence, my question.

The problem is exactly that update runs an inner event loop until it drains the event queue and all the event handler callbacks launched complete. Which is fine... unless you get an event that causes you to reenter the code that calls update. It is very easy to get that wrong and end up filling up your stack with calls to update, all waiting on the innermost call to complete. (You can also hit this with vwait and tkwait.)
That's why "update is considered harmful"; you can get yourself into an awkward-to-debug mess. Rewriting to use a coroutine can make things easier by letting you avoid the inner update and instead yielding at that point, with a resume once events have been processed.

TCL_QUEUE_MARK probably is worthwhile mentioning too, but I really don't know where exactly it is used.

@Thingamabobs That's used for generating exact sequences of events, and I've never needed it myself either.

Why does tcl not remove the update command or just and just limit it to update idletasks given it is harmful and coroutine is a safer alternative? Can you point me to any example where the update command is correctly deployed?

Because sometimes it is necessary. You just need to take care of reentrancy when using it.

Can you advise me if my use of update in this MRE necessary or is there a safer/better alternative?

I would consider this articles heading rather harmful than the update command itself.
The behaviour of update has not changed since. update can be used for asynchronous callbacks/programming and is one of the strength of Tcl that no other language has. You have to place it carefully and know what you'r doing. For Tcl beginners I'd recommend to start without it, that's agreed.
Imagine if the user accientially double-clicks a GUI button. The first click calls the buttonClick procedure. But then there is a update which checks the event loop and executes the second buttonClick.
set ::count 0
proc buttonClick {} {
    incr ::count
    <do something>
    update ;# here 'count' will get 2 because of the accidential double-click
    <do something>
    <what's the content of ::count variable?>
}

Now you have in fact two buttonClick running, without the first being finished. The variable ::count (from the first buttonClick) before the update is one, but after the update is two.

Just to add: basically the problem with update() is that after you call it, anything can happen: the widget you are working on could have been destroyed by another binding, it can even call the same binding again before the first one's finished. I had a really nasty bug where calling .update() invalidated some data in the class that was called from the binding. Usually, you can just avoid .update() or even replace it with .update_idletasks() which is safer

@thomas. Can you elaborate on your statement, "You have to place it carefully and know what you'r doing."? I am trying to learn more rather than relying on trial and error which is very time-consuming. I think such clarity can help many Tkinter users interested in this matter.

The quoted book text states wrong facts, as the call to update or update idletasks is not connected to a specific widget, rather it is a call to the underlying event-loop that is also not exclusively connected to Tk. The misconception for many tkinter user seems to be that update or update idletasks are some sort of redrawing command, such as UpdateWindow which is simply not the case.
TCL_WINDOW_EVENTS are just one of the flags that are processed in Tcl's(sic!) event-loop, which is usually driven by repeated calls to Tcl_DoOneEvent. Tkinter does this by the way.
If you get into trouble with redrawing, more often than not, it helps if you just do widget configure -background color / widget.configure(background=color) on the container widget, such as a frame or window.
So update is still as dangerous as it was back in the days where the article was written and it is not a redrawing command.

As an example for what's wrong with update. Running an Tk application under Windows will most certainly lead your application to receive the WM_PAINT message, since quote:

The system sends this message when there are no other messages in the
application's message queue

Now the update message can be rendered with this pseudo code:
while Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_ALL + TCL_DONT_WAIT):
    return

Since the return value of Tcl_DoOneEvent will always be 1, since the WM_PAINT message will always be available, you won't come out of this while loop. Now, you most certainly landed in that while event driven and you will probably reenter that code again on the next event driven basis.
Your code will end up like this:
while Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_ALL + TCL_DONT_WAIT):
    while Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_ALL + TCL_DONT_WAIT):
        while Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_ALL + TCL_DONT_WAIT):
            ...

You will do this till you ran out of space. If you don't find this problematic enough, you are only left with the timing issue mentioned it the article that you can spend time with instead of using appropriated calls to solve your issue in the first place.

I do practice using different/unique background colours for different widgets to troubleshoot appearance issues. Learnt it from @BryanOkley. Very useful method. Hence, figured out that my raised widget was illogically showing the background colour of the widgets in which it was placed instead of its defined background colour. I think there must be use cases for .update and hope to better understand this topic.

If you want to discuss your broken code, you should raise a question with a [mre].

BTW, Alan's writing did not state the .update method is connected to a specific widget.

on a widget implies in my understanding that just events outstanding on that widget are processed, which is simply not true.

I read it with the 1st paragraph in mind, i.e. .updates() relates to doing something to the event queue (i.e. mainloop). Btw, I could not reproduce the phenomenon in a MRE. I would have gone that route if I could. Thank you for wanting to help. Yes, I am aware that using .update() can be dangerous. However, I think it would be even more helpful for users to have detailed documentation on when and how to use the .update() method safely.

I don't think there is an absolute safe way of calling update. For me on a Windows platform there is a great chance that the window manager never stops to send the WM_PAINT message to my window, hence there is never an empty event queue and I would stack all of these update calls till I ran out of space. Further, if you ever find the tcl interpreter useful and use different event sources, you will get into trouble more easily. As example

Thank you for the hyperlinks. May I know what Tcl_DoOneEvent(0) does?  I did not find 0 to be one of the flags of Tcl_DoOneEvent. Pardon me, I am not a C programmer. Also, I noticed that you are referencing a static PyObject called _tkinter_tkapp_mainloop_impl, meaning this reference relates to .mainloop() method? Do you have the hyperlink for the .update() method in cpython?

0 = OneEvent + Waiting for a new event to occur. The update method is just implemented as tk.call('update'), so it executes the update method just as it would be in tcl.

Reading tcl doc on update, it looks like tkinter's .update_idletasks() method is tcl implementation of tcl's update command with the idletasks argument. It also states, "The update command with no options is useful in scripts where you are performing a long-running computation but you still want the application to respond to events such as user interactions; if you occasionally call update then user input will be processed during the next call to update."

Can you take a look at my MRE? Thanks.

I found another interesting tcl article on the update method. Quoting a section from it:

KBK 2000-02-12: My personal opinion is that update is not one of the
best practices, and a programmer is well advised to avoid it. I have
seldom if ever seen a use of update that could not be more effectively
programmed by another means, generally appropriate use of event
callbacks. By the way, this caution applies to all the Tcl commands
(vwait and tkwait are the other common culprits) that enter the event
loop recursively, with the exception of using a single vwait at global
level to launch the event loop inside a shell that doesn't launch it
automatically.
The commonest purposes for which I've seen update recommended are:

Keeping the GUI alive while some long-running calculation is
executing. See Countdown program for an alternative.
Waiting for a
window to be configured before doing things like geometry management
on it. The alternative is to bind on events such as  that
notify the process of a window's geometry. See Centering a window for
an alternative.

What's wrong with update? There are several answers.
First, it tends to complicate the code of the surrounding GUI. If you
work the exercises in the Countdown program, you'll get a feel for how
much easier it can be when each event is processed on its own
callback.
Second, it's a source of insidious bugs. The general problem is that
executing update has nearly unconstrained side effects; on return from
update, a script can easily discover that the rug has been pulled out
from under it. There's further discussion of this phenomenon over at
Update considered harmful.


I do not agree. There are valid cases when update actually simplifies the code. Imagine a sequence of measurements, all of them waiting for TCP responses from a device. Splitting the sequence into several parts would make the code unreadable.
